# Connecting two databases

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I connect two separate databases so that when some update is performed on a piece of data on one database , the change happens also on the data in the other one .?

Comment: try to have a look at replicas

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here, do you really need to be doing this?  Things get much more complex e.g. with transactions.  What should happen if an insert to the first database succeeds but the second one fails?  Do we rollback everything or wait until the insert to the second DB can succeed?

Comment: Is there a less complex way ?!

Answer (score 0):

this is really simple you must have 2 databases, 1 must be marked as a master, while other db must be slave. you 'll always insert data in master database, which will replicate this to slave database.
you must be careful because every change on master will be replicate to slave. 
to understand the entire process here I am referring you to read this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql)